Suggestions regarding a recommendation system
I am trying to build a recommendation system that selects a model (and any loras if necessary) based on a prompt. I have data that is basically a directory of images and a json file that gives information about each image (name, what prompt, what negative prompt, which model, lora used, etc.)
I want to build a recommendation system that learns from this data and helps select models, loras when given a certain prompt.
In other words:

input: prompt

output: model name, lora name, and other config settings.


Here are my questions:

How do I structure my data? In my dataset, I want to have a binary
column which reads good/bad. This basically takes into account which
generated image is good and which is bad.
What kind of architecture    seems suitable for this type of project?

